# ¿Cómo enviar los datos de mi formulario a php cuando esta validado en javascript?

Tags: javascript, php, formularios, aplicación-web, eventos

estoy haciendo un sitio web, utilizo una pagina para crear a unos usuario y utilize el repositorio de un creador de contenido llamado Falcon Masters, este es el repositorio:
**https://github.com/falconmasters/formulario-css-grid.git**

Pero al darle click al boton Enviar, solo valida los datos, pero no me envia los datos a mi código php aunque el action dice a donde ir.

Como le hago para solucionarlo?

-El archivo php se llama crear.php

Este es el codigo javascript de evento submit:

```
const formulario = document.getElementById('formulario');

formulario.addEventListener('submit', (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    const terminos = document.getElementById('terminos');
    if(campos.nombre && campos.password && campos.correo && campos.telefono && terminos.checked ){
                
        document.getElementById('formulario__mensaje-exito').classList.add('formulario__mensaje-exito-activo');
        setTimeout(() => {
            document.getElementById('formulario__mensaje-exito').classList.remove('formulario__mensaje-exito-activo');
        }, 5000);

        document.querySelectorAll('.formulario__grupo-correcto').forEach((icono) => {
            icono.classList.remove('formulario__grupo-correcto');
        });
    } else {
        document.getElementById('formulario__mensaje').classList.add('formulario__mensaje-activo');
        setTimeout(() => {
        document.getElementById('formulario__mensaje').classList.remove('formulario__mensaje-activo');
        }, 5000);
        
    }
});
```

Si pueden checar el código del repositorio, se los agradecería.

Comment: en ninguna parte veo que hagas una petición POST para hacer el envio de datos

Comment: Como dice que comentario del amigo arriba, no estas enviando el formulario en ningún momento. Deberías hacer algo como esto `formulario.submit()` o enviar una petición **ajax** si es lo que quieres ya que con el `e.preventDefault();` estas evitando su envió

Comment: listo ya lo solucione, mejor quite el evento y se lo puse a un **checkbox** y ahora ya envía los datos, pero gracias por sus comentarios @Josbert  y

Comment: @Christian, gracias

Answer (score 0):

Te hace falta el `request` con método `post` para enviar datos al servidor, te recomiendo algo así y de paso comienza a usar `json`:

```
var url = 'https://example.com/profile';
var data = {username: 'example'};

fetch(url, {
  method: 'POST', // or 'PUT'
  body: JSON.stringify(data), // data can be `string` or {object}!
  headers:{
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
  }
}).then(res => res.json())
.catch(error => console.error('Error:', error))
.then(response => console.log('Success:', response));
```

Documentación:

https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch#enviando_datos_json
https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_httpmethods.asp
https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_ajax_get_post.asp